# Why doesn't regular expression alternation (A|B) match as per doc?

Tags: python, regex

When I run the below statement in python 2.7,

```
re.search('eagle|cat', 'The cat is an animal. The eagle is bird').group()
```

I'm expecting to see `'eagle'` as result as per regular expression doc
But I'm getting `'cat'`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Why would that be? There is a matching `cat` in the string *first*.

Comment: It would improve your question if you would edit it to explain what you think the docs say alternation implies.

Comment: I'm not sure if you already found what you need, still,  you may want to take a look at lookahead and lookbehind - http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A regular expression with alternative patterns (separated by `|`) does not scan the whole string for the first alternative, then the second.

Instead, each alternative is considered at *each position in the input string*. So at position 0, neither `eagle` nor `cat` match, but at position 4, `cat` matches, even though `eagle` was tried first.

Thus, `cat` is returned as the match; the rest of the string no longer needs to be considered.

The alternative ordering matters when *both* patterns would match *at the same location*. So `cat|cats` would return `cat`, always, even if there is an `s` after that word in the input string:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search('cat|cats', 'Like herding cats.').group()
'cat'
>>> re.search('cats|cat', 'Like herding cats.').group()
'cats'
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess @martijn answered very well to your question, still, I would like to point that you can use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure that `cat`  in never followed by `eagle`, but,  if `cat` comes after `eagle`, will be matched:

```
re.search('eagle|(?!.*eagle)cat', 'The cat is an animal. The eagle is bird.').group()
```

Matches `eagle`

---

If `cat` comes after `eagle`

```
re.search('eagle|(?!.*eagle)cat', 'The cat is an animal. The eagle is bird, cat is a feline.').group()
```

will match `eagle` and the 2nd `cat`.

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/wX2xY2/1

Answer (score 0):

**Note: Relating to the accepted answer:**

`(cat|cats)` is ambiguous and it depends on the regular expression engine on how that ambiguity is resolved. This is explained well [here](https://blog.robertelder.org/regular-expression-alternation).

Comment: [Here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) is another good reference discussing this